# Websocket connection issue in https

Tags: phpwebsocket

Websocket connection works in http but not in https.

Received the error message as "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing".

Please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a reverse proxy where your socket communicates through.

If you're using nginx, you can use the following config-snippet in your location tag: [(source)](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

If you're using caddy, you can use the following config-snippet: [(source)](https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy)

```
proxy / http://app {
    transparent
    header_upstream X-Forwarded-Ssl on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am using Apache webserver with PHP in Amazon AWS linux Environment.

Comment: I am using the below code. Please help to resolve the issue.

//handshake new client.
$secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
 $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
 //hand shaking header
 $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
 "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
 "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
 "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
 "WebSocket-Location: wss://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
 "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
 socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));

Comment: Why are you manually adding a header? I don't know about apache, but usually headers are written automatically, no? Usually you manipulate the header on reverse-proxies, which can cause errors like yours